# Testing sysfs thermal driver APIs

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, temperature, sysfs

I'm setting and reading different values of the temperature threshold. I set it by echoing the value to the following file:

`/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zoneN/trip_point_X_temp`

It works fine but how do I verify the behavior through logs? Is there any specific log in the output of `dmesg` that could be useful or states the threshold has been modified? I'm trying to read through demsg output but I don't think I was able to find something relevant, though given the amount of the output, I might have missed something (is there any specific log that I should be looking for instead?)

Other things I tried:

- Ran `thermal-engine` in `adb shell`, I get `read sensor info form file failed`
- Ran `udevadm monitor` but I don't see any events

Using [this as a reference](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/thermal/sysfs-api.html)

Comment: It's a sysfs ABI. So you may read back values and see if it's the same as you wrote.

Comment: yes but shouldn’t I see some sort of event or message in the kernel of a certain action?

Comment: If your call finishes w;/o error then value got to the kernel. What happens there is solely dependent on the drivers / frameworks / etc.

Comment: but how do you verify it got to the kernel though?